# Does CPython officially support Android?

Tags: python, android, android-ndk, cpython

I see there are many "Android"s in the codes, comments, issues, PRs of cpython's repository. However, I cannot find any documents telling me how to build it for android. What's the status of cpython's supporting for android? Is there any project similar to https://github.com/beeware/Python-Apple-support? Or can I build it by simply./configure && make with few arguments?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Android?

Comment: @wkl I have read this page carefully. Firstly, these project are not well maintained. Non of then support the latest cpython. Secondly, non of these projects aims at simply build cpython itself for Android. For clarifying, what I want is an Android version of https://github.com/beeware/Python-Apple-support

Comment: That page linked to BeeWare and if you look at their repos they have an android one: https://github.com/beeware/Python-Android-support - considering that they have to patch all the CPython sources the answer to your title is “no, Android isn’t officially supported”

Comment: I have no idea why would I totally ignore it.. Maybe that's because the wiki said it support only Python 3.4. Actually it support 3.11 according to it's README. Thanks a lot.